# Multithreaded debugging in java

Tags: java, multithreading, intellij-idea

I have a program that runs about `50 threads`. I employ a producer consumer design pattern to communicate data between the threads. After the program has been running for a while, sometimes it freezes due to one of the BlockingQueue's I use to distribute data between the threads becomes full, and therefore the main distribution part of the program blocks when it tries to add data to this BlockingQueue. In other words, one of the threads stops for some reason and then the blockingQueue it uses to receive data becomes full.

How do I go about debugging this in an efficient manner? I have tried surrounding the content in all `run()` methods with `catch(Exception e)`, but nothing is ever thrown. I develop in `Java/IntelliJ`.

Any thoughts, ideas or general guidelines?

Comment: Could you post some code, please?

Comment: Simplify your program down to remove bits which don't cause the problem.  Your problem appears to be the consumer of the queue which is filling up.  Why isn't that consumer reading fast enough?  Hvae you considered using an ExecutorService which wraps a queue and a thread pools. Often this is easier to use than writing your own thread pool and queue.

Comment: You could use some tool like jstack (or jconsole) to produce a thread dump and see what your consumer threads are doing at that time. Maybe you have a deadlock which is utterly hard to reproduce on a step-by-step basis

Comment: The program is pretty big which makes it hard to isolate relevant code. @Claudio The weird thing is that when I do a thread dump, all I see is threads being blocked by a queue.

Comment: Blocked when reading the queue? Are you sure then that you queue is full and not empty? Are producers blocked in the queue too?

Comment: _...all I see is threads being blocked by a queue._  If the queue is not empty, then the consumer thread will not block on it.  Are you certain that the consumer thread is not blocked on something else?.  Are you certain that the consumer thread is even _there?_

Comment: _I have tried surrounding the content in all run()-methods with catch(Exception e), but nothing is ever thrown_.  Just a thought:  OutOfMemoryError is not an Exception, and so it will not be caught by your handler.  How do you know that it wasn't an OOM or some other non-Exception Throwable?

Comment: @jameslarge Thanks for the insights, I didn't know that OOM wasn't thrown. To clarify: all the consumers block at an empty queue, and one of the producers block at a full queue.

Comment: If I had to guess, you need to isolate your producer and consumer threads. Have one pool for producers and one for consumers. Mixing them will cause issues. All threads will block waiting for tasks or all threads will block waiting to insert...

Comment: As it's implemented now, I have one main producer, which then put an object into a consumer. This consumer then puts another object into another consumer. This seconds consumer then puts yet another object into the first consumer. I have set a very large BlockingQueue capactity to avoid them blocking eachother, but the problem still arises.

Comment: @jameslarge is it possible that OOME for any of the threads wouldn't show up in the console output?

Comment: Can't make any guarantees about what will or won't happen after OutOfMemoryError has been thrown.  There is only one heap:  If it's full for one thread, then it's full for all threads (including standard library threads that you did not explicitly create).  If it's really full, then even writing to the console may be impossible.  My original comment was to point out that _your_ handler catches and logs `Exception`s, but `OutOfMemoryError` does not extend `Exception`.  What the default uncaught exception handler does with it in your JVM, I do not know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Debug it" by using a logger. I like [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html).

Set up `log.debug` statements before and after each critical operation. Use `log.entering` and `log.exiting` calls at the start and end of each method.

While you are 'debugging' you'll run your application with the logger set to a very low level (FINEST) then run your application and watch the logging statements to learn when it fails and what the state is when it fails.

Since you're worried about a threading issue, make sure your log format includes the thread name or number.

Answer (score 1):

> general guidelines?

I don't know if this applies to your situation, but a very important guideline is to never have locks being taken in different orders.

An example:

Thread 1:

```
ResourceA.lock();
ResourceB.lock();
...
ResourceB.unlock();
ResourceA.unlock();
```

Thread 2:

```
ResourceB.lock();
ResourceA.lock();
...
ResourceA.unlock();
ResourceB.unlock();
```

Now if thread 1 is interrupted when it already owns `ResourceA` but not yet `ResourceB`, and thread 2 is allowed to run, thread 2 will take `ResourceB`. Then thread 1 owns `ResourceA` and waits for `ResourceB`, and thread 2 owns `ResourceB` and waits for `ResourceA`, so you have a deadlock.